# How to open a website in Safari in Recovery mode

Tags: macos, mac, safari, recovery

On macOS Desktop, if I want to open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) from Terminal

That's easy

Just enter:

```
open -a Safari http://www.google.com
```

Then Safari will run and open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

But, when I want to do the same thing on Mac Recovery's Terminal, it doesn't work. There's no `open` command.

[image: run 'open' on terminal]

If I run another command:

`/Application/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari`

Yes, it worked, but I have to type the [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in Safari, it's not good enough.

I want to let Safari autorun and auto-open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

I try:

`/Application/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari www.google.com`

But the result :

[image: visit google on Recovery terminal]

The Recovery version is 10.11.6, I repeat that on 10.15.7 and 11.6.1 and 12.3, and all the same.

Does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: If it's just google.com, one can set the homepage as google.com

Comment: how to  set the homepage in recovery terminal?

Comment: Is macOS already installed when you are in Mac Recovery's Terminal?

Comment: macOs not installed

Comment: Why are you trying to do this - perhaps there is another way to get the end result. You don't really want to do much in recovery mode

Comment: Yes, In fact I want to open a image from Recovery Terminal ,But There is no image viewer ,So I think visit the image url from safari is another way to see the image

Comment: I am curious too @mmmmmm this and the [QR code in recovery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/439533/5472) make for a compelling back story of setup automation and fleet management perhaps?