# How to access apple support website from safari in recovery mode

Tags: safari, imac, recovery

I am repairing an old iMac and I am trying to reinstall the operating system. Since I can't use another iMac, I am trying to reinstall the OS using [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/431897/17) guide by David Anderson, which was submitted as an answer to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431445/trying-to-reinstall-macos-after-wiping-hd-but-cant-get-past-apple-id-and-safa) question.
It is pretty well written but as I get to step 3, where it requires me to go to a support.apple.com link, and I am met with this screen [image: telling me that Safari can't establish a secure connection]. I am not sure of a way to fix safari while I am in recovery mode. So I am asking here if there is a way to get safari to let me enter the page

Edit1: this is a late 2009 mac that I am pretty sure should be running Yosemite [image: this is the hardware overview, if it helps at all]
And Safari is on version 8.0.5

Comment: David writes excellent guides on this though you might want to [edit] your question with the particular vintage Mac and version of macOS/Safari you’re running so that your  particular question can be addressed

Comment: @Allan I have made the requested changes, I hope it can help pinpoint a solution.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/439434/489896

Comment: Does it have a working Internet connection? Can you browse other sites?

Comment: AnthonyP: You could use the URL: `http://maclinks.publicvm.com/`. There is also a secure URL: `https://maclinks.publicvm.com/`. However, your version of Safari may not work with the secure URL.